# How to share scope value across states using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm calling a function in ng-init and storing value in a array to use that in ng-repeat.How could i use that array across some states within same controller and different controller.

I found

```
 app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams)
      {
          $rootScope.$state = $state;    
          $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;    
      }
]);
```

but it is not working

If i'm using $rootScope.arr=[]; than it is available across states but not with $scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should use params in your router. This allows you to pass information between two (or more) states. Assuming UI-Router usage for example, you'd set up a state like this to pass along parameters in the url string:

```
state('state-one', {
  url: '/new?itemId',
  templateUrl: 'index-one.html'
})
```

You can access that variable in your controller by adding this into the state (or alternatively, have a completely separate controller file):

```
controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
}
```

To navigate between two states and pass that information along in the template:

```
<a ui-sref="state-one({ itemId: 1 })">State One</a>
```

Similarly you can also set up the state to have the parameters available, and pass along information in them:

```
state('state-two', {
  url: '/two',
  templateUrl: 'index-two.html',
  params: {
    itemId: null,
    itemObject: null
  }
})
```

To move between states without using template links:

```
$state.go('state-two', { itemId: vm.someId, itemObject: { some: object } });
```

In your case this would work:

```
state('state-three', {
  url: '/three',
  templateUrl: 'index-three.html',
  params: {
    array: null
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

In state-two's controller (for example) to move to state-three and preserve the array for state-three to use:

```
$state.go('state-three', { array: $scope.myArray })
```

This assumes $scope.myArray is assigned to your array in your state-two controller. You're using 'array' as the value in the params, so when you access it again in state-three's controller you'll be doing your logic on $stateParams.array - assigning it in there to something that that controller (state-three's) can use, like:

```
$scope.myArray = $stateParams.array;
```

If you're using this in an ng-repeat (the 'vm' is the controller's $scope):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.myArray">
```

Comment: how to do this with array of elements.

Comment: in ng-repeat should i use array or myArray.

Comment: how to do this within the same controller.

Comment: You wouldn't do this in the same controller; it's better separation to have a controller per state.

Comment: So i can not use $scope value in different states with same controller?

Answer (score 0):

Define your html template state in app.js like this:

```
  .state('booklist',{
            url:'/booklist/:array',        //eg- I am passing id and title
            views:{
            'menuContent':{
             templateUrl:'templates/booklist.html',
             controller:'BooklistCtrl'                 
             }
             }
             })
```

In your html template

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="item in array">
  <p>{{item.title}}</p>
  <p>{{item.id}}</p>
  <button ng-click = pass(array)>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

In your controller-one,

```
    $scope.pass = function(data){
          $state.go('booklist',{array:name});
    }
```

In your controller-two,

```
    $scope.arr = $stateParams.array;
```

Update

Write a function to store values in your array

```
//example
controller('ExampleCtrl',function($scope){

function loadData(){
  //you get your data here..after this
  $scope.data = [];
  for(var i =0 ; i<5; i++){
      $scope.data.push({});  //data stored in your array
  }
};

loadData();   //call the above function, no need to use ng-init 

//pass $scope.data array in to another controller

 })
```

Comment: it will not work for me because i'm loading a array in ng-init and use this array in another state.

Comment: i'm using ui-sref to navigate and same controller for both the states.using  params: {
                     ary:null
                 }   ,  $stateParams.ary = $scope.myArray; and using ary in ngRepeat.it's not working

Comment: I think scope is accessible throughout the controller,so it should accessible in any state with same controller

Comment: Yes you can use scope throughout the controller

Comment: Using $rootScope you can access the array anywhere, like within same controller, different states and different controllers

Comment: change $scope.data to $rootScope.data

Comment: Yes,to communicate between controllers $rootScope in used but within same controller $rootScope is not needed.

Comment: Ok..then do the needful.